How to increase kinetic energy transfer efficiency for railcannons?
Context
Railguns are fairly common in sci-fi. They run on electricity, which makes them cool, and you can theoretically get extremely high muzzle velocities, which is also cool, and they (can be construed) to look very cool as well.
In this particular setting a given space fleet uses primarily railcannon-type weapons on their ships; damage is done either by a high-explosive/nuclear/temporal weapon on the end of the bolt projectile (requires lower muzzle velocity since sensors required to determine remaining distance to the target or ground have to be able to survive the acceleration which is typically >1000 $g$), or just by the kinetic energy of the bolt itself.
In the former cases, limited muzzle velocity means that the bolt might end up only going at 5-10 km/s after exiting the railcannon’s accelerator, which is not very effective when distances to in-orbit targets might exceed 100 km giving them time to perform emergency orbital maneuvers to dodge the attack. This is still effective against ground targets, though, and in the event that a maximum-power kinetic railcannon strike is equivalent to spanking a baby with an ax, high explosives can detonate higher in the atmosphere to shatter the bolt into many fast-moving pieces of shrapnel that can tear up enemy infantry/destroy enemy armor on the ground.
Alternatively, if the cannon is used as a kinetic weapon, the damage goes up dramatically since this species’ accelerator tech is fantastic. Over 100 megatons of TNT’s worth of kinetic energy can get stuffed into a one-ton ultra-aerodynamic tungsten slug and dropped into the ground from high orbit in a matter of seconds. Nuclear bombs of equivalent power are much heavier/would not survive acceleration to the same speeds, so enemies on the ground can at least try to intercept the bomb, but kinetic bolts are fired and reach their targets in far too short a time for that and carry the same kinetic energy.
Desirable effect
I want this effect in space, too - a super-destroyer taking a moment to charge capacitors off the onboard fusion reactor, then causing an enemy battlecruiser to evaporate into a cloud of gaseous metal. The issue is that high-speed collisions like that are inefficient - a bolt moving at whatever impossible speeds will make metal splash and vaporize, sure, but it’ll only affect whatever it hits. If the bolt happens to miss critical infrastructure, it’ll just fly right through the armor and leave behind a little hole that, not penetrating anything important, will be nothing more than a hole that a boring old bullet would have left.
What I want is for even a glancing blow to be completely-catastrophic. Battleships in this universe are large, sometimes 500 meters across or larger, and covered on the outside in Whipple bumpers (sheets of aluminum forming spaced armor that, in real life, is exceptionally-good at dealing with light high-velocity projectiles), so dealing damage with regular bullets is difficult. The railcannon should be able to hit virtually any part of the ship (including exterior armor pieces that could very well come off the ship completely without causing fatal damage) and transfer a significant fraction, say 0.1%, of its kinetic energy to the ship in the form of heat/momentum.
This is unlikely to happen when the bolt is just a slender rod that is more likely to penetrate the armor effortlessly than slow down to transfer its energy. Is there some other type of projectile that, without any handwaving, can reliably transfer a large fraction of its kinetic energy to an enemy ship assuming that it can be accelerated to 5,000 km/s by a railcannon?
The net effect should roughly be what a nuclear explosion looks like on the ground (destruction-wise; obviously there wouldn’t be a fireball or mushroom cloud).

The [tag:hard-science] tag is ruthless. If an answer cannot prove it is correct through mathematics and/or citation, it's threatened with deletion. Considering you're talking about a fictional application of a weapon with fictional power sources and fictional slugs... you're asking for a lot to burden answers with such a threat. What's the value to you? Are you expecting people to judge your bullet technology but not your firearm or power supply tech?

Also, what research have you performed? We have these problems today. What does research into hollow-point bullets and sabot rounds teach you?

"A slender rod that is more likely to penetrate the armor effortlessly than slow down to transfer its energy": Nothing is likely to penetrate anything else effortlessly. At sufficiently high relative speed, the impact depth is proportional to the length of the projectile and the relative density of the projectile vs the target. Note that the relative speed does not matter. This is Newton's approximation of impact depth, a rather famous and important result, and I for one would not want to argue with Sir Isaac Newton FRS, Master of the Mint.

None available with this set of restrictions. Detachable armor can be constructed to prevent glancing blows from effectively applying momentum to the hull of the ship, regardless of the projectile. You anyway need a clear hit, not a glance, to transfer some kinetic energy to the target. Past that, the projectile shape does not actually matter, as any material acts as a liquid if treated to impact speeds surpassing the speed of sound in that material, and liquids don't have a shape.

If you want your targets to explode as if a nuke had hit them, have you considered hitting them with a nuke? More broadly, is there a reason you're restricting yourself to kinetic-kill railguns only?

If you lose the hard science tag I can give a suggestion (spring loaded net). In addition, I assume you mean a coil gun? A railgun indeed looks cool, though the stresses are much more manageable with a coil gun and can look equally cool. A coil gun also uses the frictionless environment to it's full potential.

There are also doctrinal problems. You want a smaller gun. Not only is it easier to build but your hit probability increases.  It is better to be able to fire 10 bullets that can cripple a ship than a single one that will vaporise it.

Additionally, you do not want a spherical armour. You just want an armour that covers a single side and you point it toward the enemy.

I'm pretty sure that you can't have a ferromagnetic material at half a billion gravities (500 meters to get to 5000km/s), so I'd suggest not using a physics-based railgun. It can still have rails, use electricity, and be a gun, of course.

@gs railguns don't fire ferromagnetic projectiles. Well, they could, but the hit in conductivity would greatly reduce performance.

To make a very fast inert projectile impart more energy to a target (and less to the little parts of the target flying away from the exit wound in the same direction as the projectile), you want to increase the projectile's effective cross-sectional area. This follows from Newton's 2nd law and the assumption that cohesion forces are small compared to the force required to make the volume swept out by the projectile accelerate to the speed at which the projectile+volume mass has the momentum that the projectile had to start out with.
Since your projectiles are magic projectiles fired from a magic gun by a magic energy source at targets at least partially made of magic, I think the specifics of how you want your projectiles to achieve this are not within the bounds of a hard science answer.
Some ways that real life inert projectiles achieve this, which may or may not translate to your projectiles travelling much faster and made at least in part of magic, are:

Frangible projectiles (disintegrate and disperse inside the target).
Multiple projectiles in a group, like a shotgun blast, which disintegrate and disperse on the way to the target.
Tumbling projectiles. You have stated that your projectile is long and thin; if it is given some angular velocity about the short axis there's a good chance that it hits side-on, imparting more energy.
Tumbling bundled projectiles that can physically expand, like when they shot lengths of chain out of cannons in the 19th century.

Imparting more energy to your target with an inert projectile means imparting more energy to the target's armor, which means making the armor do its job better, so there's going to be a balancing act between hitting harder but not doing anything (we gave the energy to the target but all we did was heat up and deform the armor) and penetrating better but not hitting hard (poke a pencil sized hole in one side and blow a fist-sized hole out of the other side - great on the scale of a human, not great on the scale of the Burj Khalifa. Again, because most of your problem involves some element of magic, I think the specifics are not within the bounds of a hard science answer.

We must have been reading each others minds - as my answer is almost the same :D

As it stands, this answer does not meet the minimum requirements for hard science. There are no sources to back up your claims.

@justanotheruser if the definition of the second law or the derivation therefrom isn't clear to you, or if you think I've expressed it in a way that would be unclear to others, I'd be happy to expand on it.

No need for you to expand on it. Your answers need reputable sources regarding projectiles, kinetic transfer, and materials. It reads as conjecture and opinion. Where is the science?

DumDum Bullets, Hollow-points, Fragmentation and wound channels
So, you want this effect in Space - well, actually that really helps you. In an Atmosphere, you need a Material with enough strength and stuff to withstand the heat and aerodynamic forces imparted on it. In Space, you don't need any of that.
Which means you can use something like Lead (which is soft and maleable) or other materials with similar properties.
And a Soft material is exactly what you want. As you correctly pointed out, a hardened projectile will over-penetrate, go in one end, out the other, leaving a neat little hole. Whilst this is generally bad for pressurized space vessels, it is not the end of the world.
In many ways, the science of wound channels in bodies is similar - an FMJ round can and will pass straight through a body - and whilst it is generally regarded as less than ideal, so long as something vital isn't hit, a through-and-through wound is relatively survivable.
Expanding bullets
And so, if we consider our Space Ship to be analogous to a Human Body - what we need, for the desired effect, is the following:

Large Mass (for the maximum kinetic energy)
Large frontal area
Relatively soft (for maximum deformation)
Potentially brittle (for maximum shrapnel)

Now, I am not going to do the plastic deformation calculations (because I genuinely have no idea how to) - but I will describe it.
Imagine a projectile for a given diameter (and because of no air resistance - you want a bigger frontal surface area for maximum effectiveness) - as it hits the first layer, it starts to deform, slightly, bits break off etc.
This is a simulation of a .223 round hitting a steel plate
The above has a steel core, with a copper jacket, you can see in the simulation, the steel core remains somewhat intact, there is some spalling from the steel plate, the copper jacket deforms the most and compared to the original surface area, it has increased by about 30 percent.
This is what you want - each time it hits something, it doesnt tear right through it, you want it to deform, spall, fragment etc. At the speeds you are talking, when it hits a pressurized atmosphere, those spalled fragments will probably liquify from the air drag (especially if you have a material with a lower melting point) - and then you will get an effect inside the vessel similar to an EFP (Explosively Formed Penetrator - aka Shaped Copper charges) - whereby once the molten jet of copper penetrates the armour, the bits dont have enough energy to exit, and so you have super-hot metal bouncing around inside (doing a number on anything it hits).
This happens multiple times as the projectile passes through the vessel.
The softer the material, the more it deforms, fragments, liquifies etc and dumps its energy into the ship - the more damage it does.
In short - you want a projectile with similar terminal ballistics to a Hollow-Point or expanding bullet - that uses a soft, dense and brittle material (like Lead) with a large frontal surface area that deforms massively on impact, spalling and fragmenting.

It's worth noting that once you have a sufficiently high velocity, anything is a solid upon impact, so making the (non-) penetrator out of a soft material won't help much.

@InHocSigno - I know what you are referring to - however, the initial impact isnt so much the focus, its is the deformation and fragmentation after the initial impact.

This is overall the best direct answer. However, it still does not address the requirement that "a glancing blow" vaporizes the ship. Using your analogy of a human body, even if you used the softest most efficient bullet targeted at a leg, you would blow the leg off, not vaporize the body.

This is a Frame Challenge
I would like to consider the implications of railgun "unguided" projectiles. While 5,000 km/s seems fast. What does it mean in space?
Also, let's consider the energy required to accelerate a projectile to that speed. Without dividing into the calculations, you mentioned the super destroyer can impart 100 megatons of energy. This is equivalent to 2 Tsar Bombas. When this shot is fired, that energy will also be imparted on the ship. This will make your destroyer shine like a small sun when the gun is fired.
Space is large
For reference, high earth orbit is about 35,000km. While 5000km/s seems fast, in the context of space it is not enough. A ship 35,000km away, that just detected an adversary glow with the power of 2 Tsar Bombas, will have 7 seconds to react (minus the time that it took the EMR to reach them). That is a tiny distance for space warfare. Were you to shoot something as far as the moon (384,000km), the projectile would only arrive 70s later.
Ok, but this doesn't answer the question at all
The answer is that hard science demands consistent results. Railguns in space would provide very poor accuracy at the expense of enormous energy requirements. Against dynamic targets (things that can move), the fire to hit ratio would be dismal. Your space engineers would have deemed them unreliable for implementation in favor of other methods. As such, the projectile requirement would not exist at all.

As a note, while this frame challenge is valid when the question is tagged as hard science, it would become irrelevant if you changed it to science fiction. This may actually be what you are looking for since you mentioned "temporal" in your question, which is strictly in the science fiction realm.

Im sure you are looking for something similar to a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V-3_cannon for railguns. But that will only work on solar system scale. not on a per ship scale. Unless you make the particles really tiny.
For which we have names and measurements and way to accelerate them.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macron_(physics)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MPVhOy3mWQQ
They are very doable, very lethal, the only thing they are not is - very photogenic. Many spacebattles in scifi, are actually navel battles in disguise. And  a stream of particles at near lightspeed does not send a breachblock back, vibrations down the ship and shivers up the spine.
You could in theory "reacclerate" over and over again, if you had portals. But thats just a accelerator with extra steps.
